# Problems with integration $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{a - x}}{(1+e^{a-x})^2}dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have this integral: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{a - x}}{(1+e^{a-x})^2}dx$
I've tried to find its: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{xe^{a - x}}{(1+e^{a-x})^2}dx = | a-x = t| = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(a-t)e^{t}}{(1+e^{t})^2}dx$, then I used integration by parts:

Let $u = a-t$ so $du = -dt$ and let $dv = \frac{e^{t}}{(1+e^{t})^2}dx$ so $v = \int_{}^{}\frac{e^{t}}{(1+e^{t})^2}dx = |1+e^t = s| = \int \frac{1}{s^2}dx =-\frac{1}{s} = - \frac{1}{1+e^t}$, then

-$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(a-t)e^{t}}{(1+e^{t})^2}dx = -(-\frac{a-t}{1+e^t}|^\infty_{-\infty} - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{1+e^t})$ and here I have a problem: $\frac{a-t}{1+e^t}|^\infty_{-\infty} = \frac{a-\infty}{1+exp(\infty)} - \frac{a+\infty}{1+exp(-\infty)}$.

**As for me I was mistaken somewhere, but I don't understand where. I've tried to go another way - use $exp(a-x) = exp(a)*exp(-x)$ and there is the same problem.**

**QUESTION: where I was wrong?**

*Thanks for any help.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t=a-x$. Then $\mathrm{d}t=-\mathrm{d}x$. This will give you a minus sign. But you also need to apply your substitution to the boundaries of the integral. This gives you another minus sign.

So your substituted integral becomes

$$
I = \int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty (a+t) \frac{e^t}{(1+e^t)^2} \mathrm{d}t = a\underbrace{\int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^t}{(1+e^t)^2} \mathrm{d}t}_{I_1} + \underbrace{\int \limits_{-\infty}^\infty t \frac{e^t}{(1+e^t)^2}}_{I_2} \tag{1}
$$

First we notice that
$$
f(-t) = \frac{e^{-t}}{(1+e^{-t})^2} = \frac{e^{2t}}{e^{2t}} \frac{e^{-t}}{1+2e^{-t} + 2 e^{-2t}} = \frac{e^t}{e^{2t}+2e^t+ 1} = f(t) \tag{2}
$$
So this is an even function. From here it follows immediately that $I_2 = 0$.

Now let $u = e^t+1$ so $\mathrm{d}u = e^t \mathrm{d}t$. Then

$$
I_1 = \int \limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{e^t}\frac{u-1}{u^2} \mathrm{d}u = \int \limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{u-1}\frac{u-1}{u^2} \mathrm{d}u = \int \limits_1^\infty \frac{1}{u^2} \mathrm{d}u = 1
$$

So $I=a \cdot 1 + 0 = a$.